# When to use routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I started building my first Angular app using routing with unique url for every "main" component. But then I discovered the material and really liked what the tabs are doing.

What will be pros and cons of using angular routing together with Angular material  when I can just render pages with mat-tab-group like this:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> <app-comp1></app-comp1> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> <app-comp2></app-comp2>  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> <app-comp3></app-comp3>  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

In my application I don't need to strictly restrict access to different components views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing works off the url and allows you to access a determined component hierarchy from clicking on a link. Tabs cannot have the children states that routes do. Once your app is more complex that a few components routing makes it easy to link from one state of your app to another just with link. This is next to impossible to do without routing.

If all you need is three component on tabs then it might seem overkill for routes to you but you will soon find your app will grow past this if there is any more complexity than a few tabs. Plus you cannot link to a certain tab just with a url.